# Clients adds licenses under "My Account" --> does not update the LMA

Tags: licenses, isv, appexchange

We have clients adding seats (licenses) in their org under "My Accounts". Recurly (via Checkout) is updating the billing. But the LMA record is not updating?

Example: client has 2 licences; adds 1 license. Recurly shows 3. But the LMA still shows 2?

Is the ISV expected to update the LMA by hand?

Comment: I'm not familiar with recurly, but unless it has integration with salesforce's LMA application you would have to do this by hand. It's always possible to build some sort of integration (probably with apex).

Comment: Yikes, we're not using checkout yet but that seems like a big problem. I'd suggest you file a case to get the official answer, there has to be a way to keep your LMA license count accurate.